# Why is this not in 2NF and 3NF form?

Tags: normalization

`R = {A, B, C, D, E, F}`

Dependencies:

```
{A} -> {C,F}
{C} -> {D}
{B} -> {E}
```

a. this relation is in 1st normal form (NF). Explain why it is not in 2nd NF and not in 3rd NF.

b. make the required adjustments to convert relation to 2nd NF.

c. make the required adjustments to convert relation to 3rd NF.

Comment: As this looks like an assignment, please consider updating your question with your own attempts at solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

`{A}` determines `{C,F}`, and `{C}`determines `{D}`, so `{A}` determines `{C, D, F}`

Also `{B}` determines `{E}`,

Put together, this means `{A, B}` uniquely determines the entire row `{A, B, C, D, E, F}`. Therefore, columns `{A, B}` is a key of relation `R`.

Now, **2NF is violated** if a non-key field is determined (functionally dependent) by a proper subset of the key, which is obviously the case here for `{B} -> {E}`. i.e. part of the key {A, B} alone is sufficient to determine a non-key field `{E}`. This causes all the redundancy issues etc. and violates 2NF. So `R` is not 2NF.

To normalize `R` to 2NF, we need to decompose `R` into

```
R1 = {A, C, D, F}
```

and

```
R2 = {B, E}

R3 = {A, B}
```

Now, `{A}` is key for `R1` and `{B}` is key for `R2`, and they have no proper subsets (non-empty). {A, B} is key for `R3` and there is no non-key field in `R3`. Therefore, `R1`, `R2`, `R3` are in 2NF.

**3NF is violated** if a non-key field functionally depends on another non-key field. This is the case for `R1` where we have `{A} -> {C}` and `{C} -> {D}`, which causes similar problems with the violation of 2NF. To fix/normalize this, we can split `R1 = {A, C, D, F}` further into:

```
R11 = {A, C, F}
```

and

```
R12 = {C, D}
```

Now, it's easy to verify that `R11, R12, R2, R3` together are in 3NF.